# Edit a file on IIS Manager by wix installer

Tags: iis, installation, wix

My requirement is to edit a .xap file which is already in the IIS Manager.. when install another web application on IIS manager. (I want to add the end points of a web application in the previous web application .xap file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSIS Changing config file present in XAP file i.e. silverlight component build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961017/nsis-changing-config-file-present-in-xap-file-i-e-silverlight-component-build)

Comment: It's not an "exact" duplicate as NSIS vs WiX and an installers component vs some other installers component but I think it's close enough.

Comment: rather than calling a separate C# application...can't we do it in WIX? And is there any way to add text from a file to another file(xml) during installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Mike's answer over at:

[NSIS Changing config file present in XAP file i.e. silverlight component build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961017/nsis-changing-config-file-present-in-xap-file-i-e-silverlight-component-build/14966964#14966964)

There's two parts here:

1) Authoring the Silverlight application to use an external config file.

2) Authoring your installer to update that config file. In this case of WiX, it's the XmlConfig element in the Util extension.

The reasons for doing it this way is to have a highly reliable installer.  If you write custom actions to extract, edit and compress the XAP you'll invalidate digital signatures and introduce complexity and fragility to your deployment process.    Avoiding the temptation to do all this and just use XmlConfig gives you a robust, declarative installation that fully supports the Windows Installer rollback story.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom action to:

1. Open the .xap file (it's a .zip file named differently)
2. Extract the file(s) that need to be modified
3. Edit the extracted file(s)
4. Re-zip the extracted file(s) back into the .xap file.

You could find the existing .xap file using AppSearch of some sort. Maybe a `FileSearch` element.  Most of the work is going to be in your custom action though. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I would not do this. This question is a dupe and I'll try to find the other.  The easier/better thing to do is write the application so that it references a settings.xml that's stored outside of the XAP file and then use XmlConfig to update that file.

Comment: BTW, what put this XAP there?  If it does a repair it would likely undo your changes.  Whoever owns that XAP needs to enhance their story to support this use case.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions